# Pokemon Go Google Mail Account

Tags: technical-issues, pokemon-go

I accidentally logged out of Pokémon Go.

Unfortunately the email address I used was disabled. When it asks me to login with my old email I get an error message about it being disabled.

Is there any other way I can login without losing all my progress. Or do I have to create a new account and start all over again.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: This won't help you get your account back, but I would suggest creating a new email account specifically to use for games. It might help you avoid this problem in the future.

Comment: Thanks for advise. I would have done used my personal email if I knew the school was going to migrate our mail to a new account.                     Just annoyed cause I have a feeling all my pokemons are gone and I had some really good ones.

Answer (score 0):

What exactly happened? I'm a little confused, did Niantic ban or soft-ban your login info? or is it just that your google account that you were using to login and mark your pokemon go account data (items, mons, etc) with is now deleted, rendering it useless as a login?

If your login stopped working randomly but your google account is fine for email and such, i suspect you did something (apk tampering, hacks, etc) that prompted Niantic to drop the ol' banhammer on you.

If however you decided to delete your google account and it's data, I believe that you're simply screwed. Google doesn't allow recovery of deleted accounts past 3 days the last time i checked, and after it's gone, it's gone.

Comment: Hi. Sorry for delay, but I was working doubles the last two days. Yes the google account I used for the login has been deleted and therefore is useless as a login.

Comment: The google account was actually changed by the school I go to a different account.                                                                                    For example the google account used to be user name@suny.schoolname.com.  Now it is just username@schoolname.com.                                                                    Is there's no way that support can change it for me if I give them all my info as well as nickname? Thanks for any help.